# Conditional Independence problem

Tags: probability, independence

Given $A$ is conditionally independent of $B$ given $C$. i.e.,$P(A|B,C)=P(A|C)$. How do I find the $P(A,B)$ in terms of $P(A), P(B)$ or $P(C)$?

$P(A,B)=P(A \cap B)$

Comment: Is $P(A,B)=P(A\cup B)?$ (not familiar with the notation...)

Comment: You can't.  Suppose $A=C$.  Then (assuming $A\cap B\neq \emptyset$) Both $P(A\,|\,B,C)=P(A\,|\,C)=1$ but $P(A\cup B)$ is not determined by $P(A),P(B)$.